# i had server error which i need help debugging...java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CATEGORY' does not exist

Tags: java, html, sql, xml, netbeans

I'm working with netbeans. Designing a database-driven website for an online retail store. I got errors after writing the code for my homepage

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    SELECT * FROM category
    : Table/View 'CATEGORY' does not exist.
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
    Table/View 'CATEGORY' does not exist.
    org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: 
    Table/View 'CATEGORY' does not exist.
```

Please I need help debugging the error and getting my homepage up & running...

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/affablebean.css">
        <title>Groceries</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <sql:query var="categories" dataSource="jdbc/affablebean">
            SELECT * FROM category
        </sql:query>


        <div id="indexLeftColumn">
            left column

            <div id="welcomeText">
                <p>[ welcome text ]</p>

                <!-- test to access context parameters -->
                categoryImagePath: ${initParam.categoryImagePath} productImagePath: ${initParam.productImagePath}
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="indexRightColumn">
            <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">
                <div class="categoryBox">
                    <a href="category?${category.id}">

                        <span class="categoryLabelText">${category.name}</span>

                        <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg" alt="${category.name}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>

            <a href="#">
                <span class="categoryLabelText">dairy</span>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <span class="categoryLabelText">meats</span>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <span class="categoryLabelText">bakery</span>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <span class="categoryLabelText">fruit & veg</span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error cannot be more clear, does your DB actually have that table or view?

Comment: yes it does...my DB has the category table

Comment: I made a previous mistake coding my homepage, but i have updated my homepage:

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your `sql:query` `JSTL` like this:

```
   <sql:query dataSource="${jdbc/affablebean}" var="categories">
    SELECT * FROM category;
   </sql:query>
```

With using `${...}` for `dataSource`, of course be sure `jdbc/affablebean` is the right name.

And it same you are missing the `datasource` something like this ex:

```
   <sql:setDataSource var="jdbc/affablebean" driver="someNameofDriver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"
 user="root"  password="password"/>
```

For more info go to [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_setdatasource_tag.htm)

Comment: i did like u said, but i got new error message...javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 'dataSource' is neither a String nor a javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: see the link above @clique

Comment: Error:    'dataSource' is neither a String nor a javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: Error:   'dataSource' is neither a String nor a javax.sql.DataSource      (what does it mean?)